# Google AJAX API inurl: (Non-Javascript Enviornment)

Tags: ajax, url, google-search-api

thanks for taking the time to look.

I'm trying to get results from the following request:

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=inurl:nphMotionJpeg

I'm getting a valid 200 server response but no results, even though searching for inurl:nphMotionJpeg in Google returns about two pages.

The response, shown below indicates that there are more results to be viewed, however when I visit that URL or append the q variable to the previous request I get the same 200 response and no results.

```
{"responseData": 
  {"results":[],
   "cursor":{"moreResultsUrl":"http://www.google.com/search?oe\u003dutf8\u0026ie\u003dutf8\u0026source\u003duds\u0026start\u003d0\u0026hl\u003den\u0026q\u003dinurl%3AnphMotionJpeg"}
  }, 
  "responseDetails": null, 
  "responseStatus": 200
}
```

Could anyone shed light on this issue? I have tried searching inurl: strings which have a higher number of responses such as inurl:test, these work.  Is there a variable that can be appended to the query to 'seach deeper'? I've looked through the documentation and it's eluding me so far.

Thanks in advance!